# Unit testing Silverlight mocking WCF client

Tags: silverlight, wcf, unit-testing, mocking

I have SL code

```
public void LoadData()
{
    MyClient myClient = new MyClient();
    myClient.MyMethodCompleted += new EventHandler<MyMethodCompletedEventArgs>(myMethod_MyMethodCompleted);
    myClient.MyMethodAsync();
}
```

then the completed method sets properties from what is returned from the server.

Works fine, but I want to unit test the class and the properties are all private.
I expected to do something along the lines of

```
public void LoadData(IMyClient myClient = null)
{
    if(myClient == null) {
        MyClient myClient = new MyClient();
    }
    ...
```

and pass in a mock, but the interface for the client does not contain the async methods but only the original server side non async methods
i.e. public ReturnType MyMethod();

So I tried using MyClient as a base class of a Mock object

```
public MyMockClient : MyClient
new public ReturnType MyMethod() 
{
     ...
```

but the base constructor causes all sorts of problems and I do not want to add another service reference to the test project.

Am I missing a trick, can this be done without any third party mocking tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you specify the `MyClient` instance in the constructor of your class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClient _client;

    public MyClass()
        : this(new MyClient())
    { }

    public MyClass(MyClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _client.MyMethodCompleted += ...
    }

    public void LoadData
    {
        _client.MyMethodAsync();
    }
}
```

Then you can either subclass MyClient (or better yet, refactor it to implement an interface) to implement your mock version of the client.

**In response to comments**
In order to implement an interface on the auto-generated WCF client class, you can use [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  For example, assuming your auto-generated client is called `MyClient` in the namespace `MyNamespace`, your partial class would need to look like the below:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClient : IMyClientInterface
    {

    }
}
```

Assuming that the generated `MyClient` contains all of the members on `IMyClientInterface` then no further code is needed and you can construct your class on an instance of `IMyClientInterface`

Comment: Except I can not create a new instance of MyClient as the WCF service creator has made it so I have deal with it live, needs an endpoint address and access to the service reference in the project holding the class under test.
Nor can I make the MYClient impliment an interface as each time the service is updated the class gets regenerated automagically.

Comment: @rob, you could use a partial class to implement an interface if the auto-generation is causing you problems.  Would that work for you?

Comment: @Steve Greatrex, the partial class idea worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @rob No problem - you might want to mark this as the answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface of your choosing and then create and adapter wrapper that talks to MyClient like so:

```
public interface IClient
{
    void Foo();
    int Bar();
}

public class MyClientAdapter : IClient
{
    private MyClient Client { get; set; }

    public MyClientAdapter(MyClient client)
    {
        Client = client
    }
    public void Foo()
    {
        Client.Foo();
    }

    public int Bar()
    {
        return Client.Bar();
    }
}
```